# How to save file in Preferences?

Tags: java, android

I have a list of files in external storage, what I need to do is to save these files's paths in Shared Preferences, so then, when the user starts the app, I can take that path and open those files.
I've tried with saving an string set, but it doesn't seems to work, what would I do?

Answer (score 0):

`File`s cannot be saved in the `SharedPreferences`. `SharedPreferences` are used to store simple values like `String` , `Int` , `Double`, `Float` etc. In any other case you will need to use some database or something. The only thing you can do with the `SharedPreferences` is to save the File's **path** as a string to access it later in the application.